# Include variance in regression on mean values

Tags: regression, variance, mean, pseudorepliction

I have a data set on a biological variable in a wild population. I am interested in how that variable changes with respect to an environmental variable, temperature.

Given the constraints of sampling, I have a single temperature metric per year (essentially mean annual temperature).

Is there a better option than either regressing the mean value on temperature or regressing all the values on temperature?

The first option discards all the variance information within each year, but the second method seems to be the text-book definition of pseudoreplication.

It seems like there should be some method that accurately conveys that the level of replication is year (so it only includes a single point per year), but also incorporates the variation information, but I have been unable to find anything that seems correct.